# Text to Speech in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, text-to-speech

I created code for Text to Speech and installed Microsoft Speech SDK in Windows 7. When I open this code in Internet Explorer, nothing happens.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <input type="text" name="textinput" size="30">
   <script type="text/vbscript">
    Sub SpeakIt
       Dim msg, sapi
       msg= textinput.Value
       Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
       sapi.Speak msg
     End Sub
   </script>
   <input type="button" value="speak" onClick="SpeakIt">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code will use the desktop SR engine installed on the user's machine, not the server SR engine you apparently installed (Microsoft Speech SDK is a server SR engine).  Do you want the TTS to be done on the server side?  Then you need to mark the script as 'runat=server' (I believe).

Answer (score 2):

You need brakets where you call the SpeakIt function on the **Speak** Button
So try this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" name="textinput" size="30">
  <script type="text/vbscript">
    Sub SpeakIt
       Dim msg, sapi
       msg= textinput.Value
       Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
       sapi.Speak msg
     End Sub
 </script>
 <input type="button" value="speak" onClick="SpeakIt()">
 </body>
</html>
```

Of course the user will be warned about activeX script running on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, I have to demonstrate posibility to use another installed voice.

```
<script type="text/vbscript" language="VBScript"> 
             Sub SpeakIt
               Dim msg, sapi

               msg = "Stackoverflow is the best website to find solutions!"

               Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")
               ' Use it to see installed voices   
               'For Each Voice In sapi.getvoices
               '    I = I + 1
               '    msgbox "" & (I - 1) & " - " & Voice.GetDescription
               'Next

               with sapi
                   Set .voice = .getvoices.item(1) ' I use second installed voice
                   .Volume = 100
                   .Rate = -4
               end with

               sapi.Speak msg
             End Sub

             Sub OnLoad
                SpeakIt
             End Sub
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="OnLoad()" scroll="no">
```